# Android Subscription cancellation -> How to be informed and how to test?

Tags: android

I've created a monthly subscription (7 days trial included) on Google Play.

I just bought
it and the callback via `onPurchaseStateChange` worked perfect. But afterwards i cancelled 
the subscription purchase.

I still (after 10 hours) get the info that the subscription is purchased not canceled.

- Will it be canceled after the trial period?
- Or how will this info be transfered?
- And how can i test the cancellation behavior?

Thanks for response in advance.

Regards,
Jochen

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it's kind of confusing. Here is the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html#cancellation) that explains why it happens:

> When the user cancels a subscription, Google Play does not offer a
>   refund for the current billing cycle. Instead, it allows the user to
>   have access to the cancelled subscription until the end of the current
>   billing cycle, at which time it terminates the subscription. For
>   example, if a user purchases a monthly subscription and cancels it on
>   the 15th day of the cycle, Google Play will consider the subscription
>   valid until the end of the 30th day (or other day, depending on the
>   month).

So, even if you cancel the subscription, it's still valid until the end of the current cycle.

Answer (score 0):

> Will it be canceled after the trial period?

- No, if it was canceled by user when trial period ends.

> Or how will this info be transfered?

- When your subscription expires(or canceled) you will not get any information about it in Inventory. So the size of inventory will be zero and thus you can determine that subscription(any or all) was canceled.

> And how can i test the cancellation behavior?

- Create a test SKU, set the price to 1 USD, and test it. There is no other way, and it's worth it. Rather then spending hours on searching for no results.