# Android: in app billing - cancel subscription

Tags: android, in-app-billing

According to the documentation "When the user cancels a subscription **during an active billing cycle**, Google Play does **NOT** notify your app immediately of the change in purchase state". That is, the subscription is "valid" until the end of the active billing cycle. (Until then, no new subscription can be made). But if you cancel the subscription and uninstall your app (and reinstalling it again), would that trigger a purchase state change (onPurchaseStateChange) (Since a new purchase/subscription can be made in this case) or how does it work?

I could maybe use HTTP-based API in my app to request the purchase state(?), but does it return CANCELED during an active billing cycle?

Linking also to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13877595/android-subscription-cancellation-how-to-be-informed-and-how-to-test) question.

Answer (score 7):

> > But if you cancel the subscription and uninstall your app (and reinstalling it again), would that trigger a purchase state change (onPurchaseStateChange) (Since a new purchase/subscription can be made in this case) or how does it work?

Even after uninstall/reinstall, the subscription will appear active. Because indeed, it's active. Cancellation in this context means user will not be charged automatically after the end of the current cycle.

> I could maybe use HTTP-based API in my app to request the purchase
>   state(?), but does it return CANCELED during an active billing cycle?

Yes, you can use the [Google Play Android Developer API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/index). Keep in mind that this API requires authentication tokens; and you must use the same Google Account you used to publish the apps. So this must be done on your own servers for security reasons.

But here's the funny thing: even if you use the API and check a recently cancelled subscription, it will appear to be valid.

An example of this could be this call to the API to check a cancelled subscription:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v1.1/applications/YOUR-PACKAGE-NAME/
  subscriptions/THE-SUBSCRIPTION-SKU/
  purchases/PURCHASE-TOKEN-GOES-HERE?access_token=AUTH-TOKEN-GOES-HERE
```

The result will look like:

```
{
 "kind": "androidpublisher#subscriptionPurchase",
 "initiationTimestampMsec": "1379986154994",
 "validUntilTimestampMsec": "1382621354994",
 "autoRenewing": false
}
```

So the only hint you have to know if subscription is cancelled is `autoRenewing` which is set to false. This does not mean you have to stop serving the subscription content. As the docs empathizes:

> *Important: In all cases, you must continue to offer the content that
>   your subscribers have purchased through their subscriptions, for as
>   long any users are able to access it. That is, you must not remove any
>   subscriber’s content while any user still has an active subscription
>   to it, even if that subscription will terminate at the end of the
>   current billing cycle. **Removing content that a subscriber is entitled
>   to access will result in penalties. Please see the policies document
>   for more information.***

Comment: Normally I wouldn't do this but my question has got very little views and I have no idea how to do it so would you be able to take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35729545/reflection-in-background-android) please? I would really appreciate it